# how to reset the values of a spinner?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have problem with code i am using spinner in my application when clicking spinner item its go to new activity when backpress the values of spinner not reset i want to reset the values of spinner when back press help me please

```
        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {





            if (parent?.getItemAtPosition(position)?.equals("Select branch")!!){


            }

            if(position==1){


                val aryadpt=ArrayAdapter(this@Syllabus,R.layout.text_layout,fsem)


                spin.adapter=aryadpt

                spin.onItemSelectedListener= object :AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
                    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {


                    }

                    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {

                       when(position){
                          1-> btn.setOnClickListener { startActivity(Intent(this@Syllabus,First_sem::class.java))


                          }

                          2-> btn.setOnClickListener { startActivity(Intent(this@Syllabus,Second_sem::class.java)) }

                    }}
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply reset the selection before navigating to the new Activity

```
spin.setSelection(-1)
//startActivity(...)
```